# Ionic Facebook authentication - CORS request rejected

Tags: ionic-framework

I am running ionic using Visual Studio Android emulator and trying to authenticate a user through facebook using -

Ionic.Auth.login(authProvider, authSettings, loginDetails)
.then($scope.authSuccess, $scope.authFailure);

The call fails with the message in the message: “CORS request rejected: https://api.ionic.io/auth/login/facebook”. Anyone had this problem or know how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you able to get data from other http calls?

Comment: and did you try to run ur app on browser?

Comment: Yes - to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Install [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) in your project, and add one of the follow in `config.xml`

```
<!-- Allow links to example.com -->
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />

<!-- Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix to the host, or as a suffix to the path -->
<allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com/*" />

<!-- A wildcard can be used to whitelist the entire network, over HTTP and HTTPS. *NOT RECOMMENDED* --> 
<allow-navigation href="*" />

<!-- The above is equivalent to these three declarations -->
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```